# Nginx proxy Wix site shows only blank page in browser or not found

Tags: nginx, proxy

we're trying to proxy a Wix site ( https://mgertner.wixsite.com/corkscrew-copy ) over Nginx proxy. We've tried most of the headers and cookies settings, but we still got either blank page, or wix error. We've also tried SSL proxy, but it didn't have any effect. The getcorkscrew.com returns Wix not found page, the www.getcorkscrew.com only blank page. Here's the nginx configuration (note that in getcorkscrew.com case we're using upstream and in wwww.getcorkscrew.com case not).

```
upstream wix {
    keepalive 100;
    server mgertner.wixsite.com:443;
}


server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         getcorkscrew.com;

    location / {
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_pass https://wix/corkscrew-copy;
      proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    }
}

server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         www.getcorkscrew.com;

    location / {
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_pass https://mgertner.wixsite.com/corkscrew-copy;
      proxy_pass_request_headers      on;

    }
}
```

The Wix site is set up to answer on www.getcorkscrew.com. (so maybe there is a problem with Wix inner routing).
All headers and cookies should be passed untouched. We've even started a PHP server with phpinfo(), to check what the nginx really changes and the only things, which were different were IP address (obviously), and HTTP version (which we've changed in configuration afterwards).

Thanks, Jan

Comment: There might some source check going on, because we found a `XSFR-TOKEN` cookie sent from the website.

Comment: Did you find out how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I've got a working configuration for proxying a wix site with nginx:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
        gzip off;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        add_header Host mysite.wixsite.com;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass https://mysite.wixsite.com/mywixsite;
        sub_filter_types application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript;
            sub_filter 'var publicModel = {"domain":"wixsite.com","externalBaseUrl":"https:\/\/mysite.wixsite.com\/mywixsite","unicodeExternalBaseUrl":"https:\/\/mysite.wixsite.com\/mywixsite"}' 'var publicModel = {"domain":"example.com","externalBaseUrl":"http:\/\/example.com","unicodeExternalBaseUrl":"http:\/\/example.com"}';
            sub_filter_once off;
        }
    }
}
```

where `example.com` is your `getcorkscrew.com`, and `https://mysite.wixsite.com/mywixsite` is your `https://mgertner.wixsite.com/corkscrew-copy`.

Check also [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064585/proxying-site-via-nginx-results-in-blank-page) and its comments.

Answer (score 0):

Update from 2023. Wix internals seem to be changed so previous sub_filters don't work anymore.

Got it working with the following configuration.

Note that this concrete config was tested with Premium account and no domain tied to the website. As soon as you connect a domain to Wix site, add corresponding filters.

```
location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
    gzip off;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host "";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For "";
    proxy_set_header Referer https://username.wixsite.com/sitename;
    add_header Host username.wixsite.com;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass https://username.wixsite.com/sitename/$1$is_args$args;

    sub_filter_types text/html application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript;
    sub_filter "https%3A%2F%2Fusername.wixsite.com%2Ffinsimco" "https%3A%2F%2F$http_host";
    sub_filter "https%3A%2F%2Fusername.wixsite.com" "https%3A%2F%2F$http_host";
    sub_filter https://username.wixsite.com/sitename https://$http_host;
    sub_filter https://username.wixsite.com https://$http_host;
    sub_filter "https:\/\/username.wixsite.com\/sitename" "https:\/\/$http_host";
    sub_filter "https:\/\/username.wixsite.com" "https:\/\/$http_host";
    sub_filter_once off;
}
```